How to synchronize both hands when shredding guitar?
Background
I've been a long time guitar player, mainly in the (extreme) metal genre. However, I've always been a bit sloppy, either banking on "the other instruments will cover mistakes / sloppiness" or "if I can get 1/20 takes for the record, I can play it just fine enough". Recently I've decided to grind again and actually practice with nothing but a metronome and carefully listen to my playing, which already revealed some mistakes.
One type of "sloppiness" I used to play songs I couldn't really play, was to play them slightly incorrectly. For example, instead of picking every note in a fast run, I'd just use hammer-ons or pull-offs to increase my speed. As such, my left hand is clearly able to reach high speeds. OTOH (slightly intended pun), my right hand can effortlessly alternate pick 200+ bpm on a single string.
If I just shred a simple baseline melody, say 1 note per bar in 16ths, I can also swap between strings at that speed, no problem.
Now when I try to play melodic runs1, my speed drops tremendously.
Depending on the difficulty I'd say I'm usually around 110-130 bpm.
Main Question
How do I sync my fast left and my fast right hand?
I think I'm always "checking" that I do play correctly and therefore limit my speed, as I can't process quickly enough at higher bpm. Should I just "trust" that I got it down? Or that I will notice when I do a pull-off instead of playing it correctly?
Also, how "stiff" should my plec be? Yesterday evening I noticed that if I hold it more relaxed, I seem to be able to play faster (albeit suffering in tone). If I hold it more firm, the attack is clearer but the speed decreases.
1 Let's say a melodic run has usually no two same consecutive notes and may hop between (adjacent) strings irregularly.

You maybe already do some or all of these, but here goes.
Hold the pick as lightly as possible, without it being let go. Hold it so there's only a small amount showing, to pluck with. Use wrist movements rather than finger.
Always play whatever it is slowly and accurately, with regard to volume and attack on each individual note, alternating for the majority of the time.
When string hopping, try to organise things so the last pluck on one string is in the direction of the next string to be played. Not always possible, but worth going slowly enough to find out.
Only play for short periods, say 10–15 mins at a time, and stay at one tempo (with metronome) each day. Maybe the next day, try playing at what you think was the last tempo, before launching the metronome. As a datum point.
Synchronisation: find a place where the left hand isn't stretched, and practise everything slooowly until it can be done automatically — if you can recite the alphabet, or the two-times table at the same time, you're there!
Don't hold the guitar neck in a vice grip; with a well set-up guitar, it's unnecessary. Consider, for now, the angles of the guitar/neck — from above and from the side. You may find that holding the head more upright can produce a better angle for your hand/wrist/fingers. May not look as cool, but may make it easier to play. Same with slinging low — not so good for fast fretwork.
Above all, lots of practice, which may take months. You first have to unlearn the 'bad habits'!

Hey, great stuff! There's definitely something in there I didn't try yet. Are you referring to economy picking in the middle? Also do you have any comment on my question about how to check that I do it correctly on higher speeds?

Above all: relax and, if you can, enjoy. Try and avoid fretting/picking with a death-like grip. The best make it look effortless and there are probably some strong signals in that.,

@J Evans definitely guilty of that.
